# How to run Ubuntu touch on Hp Slate 21 inch tablet running jelly bean

Tags: dual-boot, android

I have an hp slate 21 running android jelly bean that needs something like ubuntu on it to make it useful.  I accept I need to root it and risk bricking it but it's not much use as it stands so not much lost
I have some but not a lot of computer knowledge so need detailed help

Comment: There seems to be no way of rooting the slate 21. So once there is a reliable way then perhaps installing Ubuntu will be possible. Did you have any progress in your efforts?